# Does liquibase changeset ordering change on subsequent updates?

Tags: mysql, liquibase

Is the CHANGESET execution in liqibase dependent on its position in the xml? For example if I have a the liquibase script as below

```
<changeSet id="20140211_001" author="test">
    <createTable tableName="alarm_notification_archive">
        <column name="id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>

        <column name="event_timestamp" type="timestamp" defaultValue="0000-00-00 00:00:00">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="20140210_001" author="test">
    <sql>ALTER TABLE `notification_archive` ADD COLUMN
        `is_Alarm_Outstanding` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE</sql>
    <rollback>
        <sql>ALTER TABLE notification_archive DROP COLUMN
            is_Alarm_Outstanding
                </sql>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

My understanding is the `changeset` ordering is:

1. 20140211_001
2. 20140210_001

If I now add another changeset in between 1 and 2

```
<changeSet id="20140211_001" author="test">
    <createTable tableName="alarm_notification_archive">
        <column name="id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>

        <column name="event_timestamp" type="timestamp" defaultValue="0000-00-00 00:00:00">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="20140212_001" author="test">
    <sql>ALTER TABLE `notification_archive` ADD COLUMN
        `is_Alarm_Outstanding` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE</sql>
    <rollback>
        <sql>ALTER TABLE alarm_notification_archive DROP COLUMN
            is_Alarm_Outstanding
            </sql>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="20140210_001" author="test">
    <sql>ALTER TABLE `notification_archive` ADD COLUMN
        `is_Alarm_Outstanding` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE</sql>
    <rollback>
        <sql>ALTER TABLE alarm_notification_archive DROP COLUMN
            is_Alarm_Outstanding
            </sql>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

will the new changeset execution order be

1. 20140211_001
2. 20140212_001
3. 20140210_001

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Liquibase reads the changeSets in order. See the [Changeset Documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html)

Answer (score 4):

Only to be more clear, Liquibase executes the changesets by the **order in the file**.

As explained [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html), the ID content does not make any effect in the execution order:

> The id tag is only used as an identifier, it does not direct the order
>   that changes are run and does not even have to be an integer.

Comment: Would it be a problem, if we include a new changeset like this in between existing ones? (if all are for different tables)